# Grouping rows into one regarding an order

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm not quite sure how to describe this scenario, which is probably why I have difficulties googling for it. I can't even say, if something like this is even possible. All I found, which goes into the right direction, would be [window functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions/), however I can't figure out how to apply it in this case.

I have a table that looks something like this (plus some more field irrelevant to the question):

```
CREATE TABLE item (marker VARCHAR(1), free TINYINT(1));

INSERT INTO item VALUES
('A', 1),
('B', 1),
('C', 0),
('D', 1),
('E', 1),
('F', 1),
('G', 0),
('H', 1),
('I', 0),
('J', 0);
```

I'd like to know how to write a query (considering an `ORDER BY marker`) that

- displays all rows with `free = 0` as they are
- and combines all consecutive rows  with `free = 1` into a single row with information which range of rows have been combined.

So the result could be something like

| marker | last_marker | free |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 |
| C | *null* | 0 |
| D | F | 1 |
| G | *null* | 0 |
| H | H | 1 |
| I | *null* | 0 |
| J | *null* | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it could be done with window functions:

```sql
with cte1 as (
    select *, case when free = 1 and lag(free) over (order by marker) = 1 then 0 else 1 end as grp_change
    from item
), cte2 as (
    select *, sum(grp_change) over (order by marker) as grp_number
    from cte1
)
select min(marker), case when free = 1 then max(marker) end, free
from cte2
group by grp_number, free
```

It works as follows:

- Mark all rows that have free = 0 or (free = 1 and previous row free <> 1)
- Do a running sum over marked rows to create group numbers
- Group the data by group numbers

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=e0057e794417b76ab0c1466f3ad0dcab)